# data accumulation with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to accumulate like this.

| timestamp | id | strength |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1383260400000 | 1 | strength accumulated by square id1 or id2 == 1 |
| 1383260400000 | 2 | strength accumulated by square id1 or id2 == 2 |

if timestamp is different, making another row.

---

here is code. but, result is below.

```
df2["strength"] = pd.to_numeric(df["strength"])
 for i in range(len(df)):
     if (df.iloc[i - 1, 0] != df.iloc[i, 0]) or \
             df.iloc[i - 1, 1] != df.iloc[i, 1]:
         k = k + 1
         print(k)
     df2.loc[k, "timestamp"] = df.iloc[i, 0]
     df2.loc[k, "id"] = df.iloc[i, 1]
     df2.loc[k, "strength"] = df2.loc[k, "strength"] + df.iloc[i, 3]
```

| timestamp | id | strength |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 4.890249263573871e-05 |
| 1383260400000 | 1 | 0.00692127440351541 |
| 1383260400000 | 2 | 0.0031095399526760983 |
|  |  | 0.0001136447068307 |
|  |  | 0.0001557162945607 |
|  |  | 0.0002134019939307 |

---

here is raw input data.

| timestamp | squareid1 | squareid2 | strength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1383260400000 | 1 | 751 | 1.0024511991972666e-06 |
| 1383260400000 | 1 | 752 | 4.636474149834957e-05 |
| 1383260400000 | 1 | 753 | 0.0001289563565283 |
| 1383260400000 | 1 | 754 | 6.849944595888879e-05 |
| 1383260400000 | 1 | 755 | 9.220729726979178e-07 |
| 1383260400000 | 2 | 1 | 5.1182385382982246e-05 |
| 1383260400000 | 2 | 55 | 5.1182385382982246e-05 |
| 1383260400000 | 2 | 56 | 3.0469237948520085e-06 |
| 1383260400000 | 2 | 152 | 8.513520849740889e-05 |

Comment: Can you explain what your expected output is?

Comment: sry for my late editing

Comment: It's sill not clear what the expected output is, you only want to accumulate when id2 is either 1 or 2?

Comment: no, when id is 1, then accumulate strength if squareid1 or squareid2 is 1

Comment: And what if you have a case that applies to both? In your example you have `squareid 1 = 2` and `squareid2 = 1`, do you want to sum it under `id = 1` or `id = 2`? Can you provide an example with easy numbers with expected result?

Comment: there is no overlapping data in dataset with same timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['group_me'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.squareid1 if x.squareid1 - 1 != x.squareid2 else x.squareid2, axis=1)
output = df.groupby(['timestamp', 'group_me'], as_index=False)['strength'].sum()
print(output)
```

Output:

```
       timestamp  group_me  strength
0  1383260400000       1.0  0.000297
1  1383260400000       2.0  0.000139
```